# Cassandra fails to write data with "Too many open files" exception

Tags: java, cassandra, distributed

I'm using Apache Spark to write data to cassandra from multiple nodes. This process lasts for about 40 minutes and then some cassandra nodes crash with the following error :

```
ERROR [COMMIT-LOG-ALLOCATOR] 2016-04-28 12:10:42,628 JVMStabilityInspector.java:139 - JVM state determined to be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data10/cass/commitlog/CommitLog-6-1461831890172.log (Too many open files)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.MemoryMappedSegment.createBuffer(MemoryMappedSegment.java:61) ~[apache-cassandra-3.5.jar:3.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init>(CommitLogSegment.java:167) ~[apache-cassandra-3.5.jar:3.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.MemoryMappedSegment.<init>(MemoryMappedSegment.java:46) ~[apache-cassandra-3.5.jar:3.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.createSegment(CommitLogSegment.java:124) ~[apache-cassandra-3.5.jar:3.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegmentManager$1.runMayThrow(CommitLogSegmentManager.java:122) ~[apache-cassandra-3.5.jar:3.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) [apache-cassandra-3.5.jar:3.5]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
```

How can this be fixed?

My cassandra cluster has 4 nodes with replication factor of 2.
Each node has Xmx and Xms parameters set to 16G
The data I'm loading is around 1.5 million images with meta data. Each image is around 10-30KB and stored in a blob column.

Comment: did you try that? http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/troubleshooting/trblshootTooManyFiles_r.html

Comment: Did you follow the recommended system settings for production : http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/install/installRecommendSettings.html ?

Comment: not yet, I'll try now

Comment: Any findings regarding this issue?